# "length in bytes" vs "length by the byte" and "paid in hours" vs "paid by the hour"

Tags: differences, prepositions, quantifiers

> 1: "The variable len indicates the buffer length in bytes."
>
> 2: "The variable len indicates the buffer length by the byte."

I'm a computer programmer, so I know **1** is far more common than **2**.

However, please consider the following two sentences:

> 3: "He is paid by the hour"
>
> 4: "He is paid in hours"

I also know **3** is far more common than **4**.

Which of these phrases should be used in what scenarios?

Comment: *paid in hours* means you get paid with monetary unit of hours, which is probably not what you want to say.  i would definitely like to be paid in dollars instead of hours  :p  in the same sense, *bytes* is the measurement unit of the buffer.

Comment: "Paid by the hour" means you'll get paid during that hour (before that hour passes).

Comment: @Z3r0n3 no, it doesn't. It means you get paid on a per-hour basis.

Comment: @thang: It might depend how much you value your own time. If I was asked to spend an hour dealing with a really taxing job, in return for being given a month off, I might give it some serious consideration!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, or equivalently the dollars equal to my time for a month.  between the two, i would prefer the dollars.  i guess i am greedy :p  well, dollar is more flexible in that i can choose not to work for a month with the dollars, or i can choose to work for a month and get more $.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two examples involve different roles for the unit. You could have, for example,

> *The variable 'len', which contains the buffer length in bytes, changes **by the minute**.*
>
> *He is paid by the hour, **in pound notes***.

It's the difference between ***by** what method? [*incl. *how often?]*, and ***in** what units?*.

Answer (score 3):

The convention is different because the objects in the expressions are different.

Both "in bytes" and "in hours" mean *in units of* said. A buffer size is actually measured in bytes, while being paid in hours is ambiguous at best. Unless someone has created an avatar of time that is now a currency, that wouldn't even be payment, it would be barter!

The expression "to be paid by the hour" refers to how the payment is *calculated*. Instead of being set *by number of commissions secured*, their pay is set *by the number of hours they work*.